# Unable to get data from sever using soket.io in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, real-time

I am trying to use soket.io for some real time task in my react project but it showing connected but nothing is receiving.
Here is what code I have written so far.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:4000');

componentDidMount(){
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(socket.connected);// connected is showing true 
    });

    socket.on('messages', (data) => { // but here nothing happening. it is not coming inside function.
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Please what might be fault here.
Your help would be highly appreciated
Thank in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a typo? `socket.on('messages')` on.('message') maybe?

Comment: Can you also post server side code sending those events

Comment: @tarzenchugh, Actually,  backed is looking some other guy but he is using that code back-end code for three more app, and  in those app it is working

Comment: @Zee,  I am sure it is `messages`

Comment: Can you see if you have any error in console, may be debug using `localStorage.debug = '*';`

Comment: @tarzenchugh, sure let me check it

Comment: no error in console

Comment: but when I check network tab  I got this  response `96:0{"sid":"Zdjgu9SNXEU7vJ65AABi","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40`

Comment: Try `socket.on('event', function(data){})` according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client;

Comment: yes, I tried like this `   socket.on('messages', function(data){
     debugger
     console.log(data)
   });`  but nothing happening